Remove/Disable some installed printers from print dialog
Is it possible to remove/disable some installed printers when the print dialog is show? from the photo below, i want to disable/remove the cutepdf writer.

I can accessed the printer names but I cant disabled it. Is there any way to achieve it? I used RDLC report viewer
